# Change default extension for WSDL resources in SoapUI

Tags: wsdl, soapui

We have an old web service which is defined to expose its WSDL via the URL pattern `//service/getorderservice.wsdl`, however when we try to use SoapUI to mock this service, it tries to use the following default URL for the WSDL: `http://service/getorderservice?wsdl`.

This make all our client tests fail because the WSDL is unaccessible. Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to make this work? I tried to create a mock service in soapUI 4.5.2 OS and i was able to create a path like your.

```
http://localhost:8088/testmock
```